# excel - filter non-static list on first three letters

Tags: excel

I'm trying to filter out some values from a non-static list, and have the results sit in another range.  So:

```
OriginalList:
ABC_1
ABC_2
z_1
z_2
```

I want to filter out anything that starts with ABC, into another list so I end up with:

```
NewList:
z_1
z_2
```

The original list can move / get mixed up.  And I can't use VBA, need this to automatically update.  And I can't have blank cells in between results in NewList.

Thanks -KC

Comment: What have you tried so far? Nobody is going to do it for you unless you show your effort and tell us what is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,3)="ABC","",1)
```

and in **B2**:

```
=IF(LEFT(A2,3)="ABC","",1+MAX($B$1:B1))
```

and then copy **B2** downwards.

Then in another cell, say **D1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(ROW(),B:B,0)),"")
```

and copy downward:

[image]

Using **B** as a "helper" column allows us to avoid array formulas.